# how to make pseudocode of perceptron in python?

Tags: python, neural-network, perceptron

This code was written in python 3, could you tell me what your pseudocode would look like? I can not understand the calculations that are being made:

```
#dobro n * 2
# x * weight

import random
import numpy as np

   def derivada(n):
        return n*(1-n)

x = 0.85 
y = 0.25
w = random.random()

#épocas

for i in range(10):
     a=np.tanh(x*w)

     e = y-a#erro

     w+= x* derivada(e)

     print(a)
```

I tried to do the pseudocode this way, but it's not working too well.

```
     algoritm "untitled"

            var
                er, n, f, x1, w1, w2, u, y : real
                                  b, yd, i : inteiro
           Begin
               b <- 1
               x1 <- 1
               w1 <- 0
               u <- (x1*w1)+b
               y <- tan(u)
               yd <- 5
               er <- yd-y
               for i de 1 to 10 do
               n <- 0.5
               f <- (n*x1*er)
               w1 <- w1+f
               Write(w1)
               endfor

               // Commands
          End
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what's happening is you have these variables:

`x` - Input value to perceptron

`y` - Expected output from perceptron

`w` - Weight value on perceptron

The `derivato(n)` function returns the derivative of the tanh curve. This is used to calculate the adjustment to the `w` variable.

`x` is set to 0.85, `y` is set to 0.25. `w` is initialized to a random number.

10 times, `a` is the output of the perceptron. This is equal to `tanh(x*w)` where `x` is the input, `w` is the weight, and `tanh` being the tanh function.

The error (`e` variable) is calculated by doing `y-a`, where y is the expected output. (the ground truth)

The adjustment to the weight (`w`) is calculated by calculating the derivative of the tanh curve at `e` and multiplying by `x`. So the adjustment is `x*derivato(e)`

Then, the adjustment is added to the weight, to adjust it.

Comment: would be like this?                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                        
               x <- 0.85
               y <- 0.25
               w <- random
                      for i of 1 to 10 do
                               a <- tan(x*w)
                               e <- y-a
                               w <-(x-e)
                               write(a)
                      endfor

Comment: Sorry, the 2nd to last paragraph is incorrect. `w` is supposed to be adjusted by the product of `x` and `derivato(e)`, not the difference. So `w <- (x-e)` should actually be `w <- w+(x*derivato(e))`

Comment: You're the best, it worked out right here. It stayed like this, w <- w + (x * tan (er)), thank you.